# Update and Destroy controller actions are unable to find object to be updated/destroyed without a hack. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing simple tests to update and destroy a forum object. As of now I have my tests passing, however, there is an extra line of code that should not be necessary in my update and destroy actions. Normally these lines would be omitted but for some reason I have to have them in order for my tests to pass. Let me explain with code below.

Here are my controller tests for edit,update, and destroy:

```
test "edit" do
  get :edit, id: @forum.id
  assert_response :success
end

test "update" do
  put :update, id: @forum.id, forum: { name: "Ruby vs. Python vs. Javascript deathmatch" }
  @forum.reload
  assert_equal "Ruby vs. Python vs. Javascript deathmatch", @forum.name
end

test "destroy" do
  assert_difference('Forum.count',-1) do
    delete :destroy, id: @forum.id
  end
  assert_redirected_to forums_path
end
```

Here are my controller actions:

```
def edit
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    #This line should not be necessary
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @forum.update(forum_params)
        format.html { redirect_to forums_path, flash: { success: t('.success') } }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to forums_path, flash: { success: t('.error') } }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    #This line should not be needed either.
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
    @forum.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to forums_path }
    end
  end

  private

  def forum_params
    params.require(:forum).permit(:name, :topics_count, :posts_count, :position)
  end
```

Notice that on update and destroy, I need to explicitly write code that finds the @forum object instance variable. Without these two lines of code, my test suite fails and I don't have any idea why.

Here is a picture of a debugger statement that I've placed in my update controller.

[image]

As you can see in the params hash, the id is included in the params, so it should have been  "found" in the update and destroy actions. What could be going wrong? Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: params hash != object in database.  You're `params` hash is telling your server the id of the object you need to find in your database, which is necessary to update or delete said object.  So in short, you absolutely need those two lines to update and destroy that object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply JTG. For updating an attribute, isn't that what the def edit method does in the controller?

Comment: No. Each http request is stateless, which means when you make an `edit` request, all your server is doing is finding the object and populating the form and sending it to the client. The end.  The server is finished with that request once it's sent.  When the client submits that form, it's a completely different http request (Which gets routed to the "update" action), your server doesn't know anything about the previous requests and must be supplied with all necessary information to complete the update.

Comment: This is of course a hypersimplified description that ignores things like cookies/sessions, but the general principle is there.  Each http request/response taken by your server is supposed to be ignorant of all previous requests/responses.